# How to visualize relationships between nodes?

Tags: oracle-apex

The following is an example of relationships between nodes. In this example D is connected to B and C, but the main route to D is A-B-D not A-C-D. So when I click the node D it should visualize its main route in yellow color or any other color. the main route for E is A-B-E, the main route for F is A-B-D-F.
which software I should use to achieve the task. Can I use oracle apex for that purpose?

[image]